# Why do electrons leaving resistors in parallel in a circuit do have the same potential energy even if not connected to a battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, voltage

We assume when resistors are connected in parallel there must be the same voltage across each of them.

It could be easy to understand why it happens when all the resistors are connected to a battery:it's the battery that keeps the potential difference (energy) existing and equilises it by its internal chemical actions; then the voltage is applied to the charge carriers (electrons) in the resistors via the low resistance (or ideal) conductors. The current in the conductors does not consume any energy, so all the energy is owned by each electron as it starts its flow through the resistors where is interely dissipated.

Consider however a circuit like this:
[image: snaphot of a circuit]
Assume that the conductors are all ideal and that there is a voltage between points 'A' and 'B'. We have a group of parallel resistors (R1, R2,R3) connected in series to another parallel group (R4,R5).

Let's focus on the first group and reason *ad absurdum*.
We know that incoming electrons (in green) must have the same potential energy, but why can't the outgoing ones have different potential energies (a "yellow" or "red" or "blue" value of electric potential) for each path? Is the potential a "property" of each electron?

**What "tells" each electron to have the same potential energy in yellow, red and blue path? How does this happen?**

**@Edit** We "assume", as I wrote at the beginning, is incorrect.
Better say "have as certain".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to think about the electric field, not the electrons. It is true that the electrons do move (slowly) but it is the electric field across the different parts of the circuit that makes this happen - and changes in the electric field propagate almost instantaneously.

If there were a potential difference between, e.g. the yellow and blue paths in your diagram, then there would be an electric field between these points; and a current would flow in order to neutralise it. Because the wire has a low resistance, the magnitude of the current would be high for only a small potential difference. This 'equalising' current would of course be composed of some electrons drifting from the area of low potential to high potential.

Comment: Nice answer. If there were a potential difference between paths, then there would be an immediate current that equalizes it on the outgoing paths beacuse there can't be any electric field in a *perfect* conductor (no energy needed and dissipated by the current) and I think that's also what happens in transient when we try to connect a fourth parallel resistor.

Comment: even if the conductors are not perfect, the voltage drop for a given current is very small (from Ohm's law). The same is true for transient changes in voltage if the wires have inductance and capacitance (to earth), due to the low impedance.

Comment: Real wires do have a non-trivial resistance: for example, 1 metre of 12  copper wire has a resistance of 17 Ω (roughly). The effect is considerably higher at higher frequencies. When I charge my car at 32A, the cable gets noticeably warm after a few tens of minutes.

Comment: Yes, real circuits just have to tend to be as the "ideal" ones. So we use what fits the necessary conditions to work as the "model" has to.

Answer (score 1):

> We assume that connecting resistors in parallel means keeping the same voltage among them.

Technically, no. We are actually assuming that wires are equipotential surfaces. So then if you have circuit components whose "left" ends are all connected by only wires, and whose "right" ends are also connected by different wires, then we can conclude based on this assumption all of the components are at the same potential difference.

In other words, the assumption is actually that your red, yellow, and blue sections are all at the same potential.

Comment: Good reasoning! Wires are "equipotential surfaces", but I think that's the result of some physical reason. Thanks for  your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The leads of the resistors are connected together since they are in parallel, so they essentially form a single perfect conductor, and there can be no potential differences in perfect conductors in steady state.

Thus, the potential difference between both sides of the resistors in parallel is the same is the potential difference between any of the resistors individually. They are essentially one resistor with a lower effective resistance, since current now has more paths to travel through.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree with you. You are right, but I think @Martin CR explain also why a potential difference cannot exist in a perfect conductor.